# Getting the longest array within a json object

Tags: javascript

I've this json data:

```
var obj = `{
    "email":"my email", 
    "message":"my message", 
    "subject":"my subject", 
    "color1":["color1-1", "color1-2", "", "color1-4], 
    "color2":["color2-1", "color2-2", "color2-3", "color2-4", ""], 
}`
```

I want to know the length of the longest array in this json after removing the empty objects, i.e. the `cleaned` object should looks like:

```
var cleaned_obj = `{
    "email":"my email", 
    "message":"my message", 
    "subject":"my subject", 
    "color1":["color1-1", "color1-2", "color1-4], 
    "color2":["color2-1", "color2-2", "color2-3", "color2-4"], 
}`
```

the longest array is `"color2"`, and its length is: `4`

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: How do you handle a tie? If there were multiple arrays with the length 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use `reduce` by taking `Object.entries`, like this:

```js
const obj = {
    "email":"my email", 
    "message":"my message", 
    "subject":"my subject", 
    "color1":["color1-1", "color1-2", "", "color1-4"], 
    "color2":["color2-1", "color2-2", "color2-3", "color2-4", ""], 
};

const result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((a,[k,v])=>(Array.isArray(v) ? (len = v.filter(Boolean).length, a = a[0]<len ? [len, k] : a) : a), [0, ""]);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: How do you handle a tie? If there were multiple arrays with the length 4

Comment: @HasanAYousef as you might know Object.entries creates an array of key value pair. And given logic return only one `key` first encountered key having maximum length and subsequent items (of same length) would be ignored.